# R leaflet uncheck layer

Tags: r, leaflet

Is there a way with Leaflet in R to have layer controls unchecked by default? I've got an addCircleMarkers layer that I want unchecked when the map loads. Here's the code snippet (I know it's not reproducible, but I'm hoping there's a simple way to do this that doesn't require running all the code).

```
  mymap%>%addCircleMarkers(data=mydata, weight = 1,color="red",radius = ~sqrt(DataPoint),group="NewLayer")%>%
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("NewLayer"),options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
```

I found this posting that describes it using leaflet directly in js, but I'm not an expert coder in js and am relying on the R interface:
[Check/uncheck overlays in groupedlayercontrol.js](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118464/check-uncheck-overlays-in-groupedlayercontrol-js)

Comment: I've never used R in my life, but docs can be helpful (sometimes). Have a look at http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html and try `mymap %>% hideGroup("NewLayer")`

Comment: duh. Thanks. If you put it as a response I'll mark as answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Layer in Leaflet control is unchecked when it's hidden (not shown on map). If you look at the official docs of Leaflet for R at http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html 
, you will notice it's possible to hide a layer with a simple call:

```
mymap %>% hideGroup("NewLayer")
```